# UITableViewCell with a UISwitch won't redraw?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a uitableviewcell which contains a uiswitch (obj-c). The switch works fine, but when a button outside the tableview is clicked I need the uiswitch in the cell to redraw and make it disabled. I am trying the following, but it won't work?  My CellForRowAtIndex is being called and my block of code is called that says disable the UISwitch but nothing happens?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        thingic NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        NSString *danID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:kSavingdanID];


        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        }


        if(indexPath.row == 0) { // Mute thing Calls

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Public Calls";
            self.thingSwitchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 13, 0, 0)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.thingSwitchView];
    //        cell.accessoryView = switchView;
            [self.thingSwitchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
            [self.thingSwitchView addTarget:self action:@selector(thingSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255.0 green: 0.0/255.0 blue: 0.0/255.0 alpha: 0.4];

        } else if(indexPath.row == 1) { // Mute boo Calls

            cell.textLabel.text = @"boo Calls";
            self.booSwitchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 12, 0, 0)];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.booSwitchView];
    //        cell.accessoryView = switchView;
            [self.booSwitchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
            [self.booSwitchView addTarget:self action:@selector(booSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255.0 green: 0.0/255.0 blue: 0.0/255.0 alpha: 0.4];

        } else {
            // do nothing
        }


        if([NSString isEmpty:danID]){
            [self.thingSwitchView setEnabled:NO];
            [self.booSwitchView setEnabled:NO];
            [cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
            [cell setNeedsDisplay];
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Never mind those other comments (deleted)... I see where you add the switches as subviews. But you should be (1) reusing those switches and (2) declaring them locally.

Comment: And in what situation would you want to turn the switch off? You haven't accounted for that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I was starting to write out an answer, but there were too many unknowns. You'd need to post more of your code. Specifically from thingSwitchChanged:

Answer (score 0):

I had a success of implementing switch cells by subclassing a UITableViewCell and using delegation.

```
@class EGSwitchCell;

@protocol EGSwitchCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)switchCellDidChange:(EGSwitchCell *)switchCell;

@end

@interface EGSwitchCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch *mySwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<EGSwitchCellDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

Hope it gives you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

First off, by adding new switches as subviews during every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you're piling new ones on top of old ones. I'd recommend you add the switches to the appropriate cells upon their creation. Similarly, I'd also recommend you set the cell's contentView.backgroundColor upon the cell's creation since it doesn't change.

And it took me a bit, but I think I see why you're making your switches class variables... I'm assuming there's only one section in your table (?) and so these switches only appear once each. If that's the case, we can use those class variables to your advantage since they can maintain their variable even when the switch changes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    thingic NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSString *danID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:kSavingdanID];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            self.thingSwitchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 13, 0, 0)];
            [self.thingSwitchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
            [self.thingSwitchView addTarget:self action:@selector(thingSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.thingSwitchView];

            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255.0 green: 0.0/255.0 blue: 0.0/255.0 alpha: 0.4];

        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            self.booSwitchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 12, 0, 0)];
            [self.booSwitchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
            [self.booSwitchView addTarget:self action:@selector(booSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.booSwitchView];

            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255.0 green: 0.0/255.0 blue: 0.0/255.0 alpha: 0.4];
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) { // Mute thing Calls

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Public Calls";

    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) { // Mute boo Calls

        cell.textLabel.text = @"boo Calls";
    }

    if ([NSString isEmpty:danID]) {
        [self.thingSwitchView setEnabled:NO];
        [self.booSwitchView setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [self.thingSwitchView setEnabled:YES];
        [self.booSwitchView setEnabled:YES];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Also make sure you're changing your `NSUserDefaults` objectForKey `kSavingdanID` as you've intended. I'd suggest posting your code from `thingSwitchChanged:` and `booSwitchChanged:` if you continue to have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in current way. You don't get the switch inside the cell using self.
`Self.thingSwitchView` and `self.booSwitchView` contains the last allocated switch. It won't be the switch inside the cell. Also even though the cell is reused, you are creating a new switch every time. That's also not a good practice.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  thingic NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  NSString *danID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:kSavingdanID];


  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  cell.selectionStyle   = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  if (cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
      cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
      cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  }

  if(indexPath.row == 0 && ![cell.contentView viewWithTag:101])
  { // Mute thing Calls
       cell.textLabel.text = @"Public Calls";
       self.thingSwitchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 13, 0, 0)];
       self.thingSwitchView.tag = 101;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:self.thingSwitchView];
       [self.thingSwitchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
       [self.thingSwitchView addTarget:self action:@selector(thingSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255.0 green: 0.0/255.0 blue: 0.0/255.0 alpha: 0.4];
  }
  else if(indexPath.row == 1 && ![cell.contentView viewWithTag:102])
  { // Mute boo Calls
       cell.textLabel.text = @"boo Calls";
       self.booSwitchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 12, 0, 0)];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:self.booSwitchView];
       self.booSwitchView.tag = 102;
       [self.booSwitchView setOn:YES animated:NO];
       [self.booSwitchView addTarget:self action:@selector(booSwitchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255.0 green: 0.0/255.0 blue: 0.0/255.0 alpha: 0.4];
   }

   UISwitch *thingSwitch = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
   UISwitch *booSwitch   = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
   if([NSString isEmpty:danID])
   {
        [thingSwitch setEnabled:NO];
        [booSwitch setEnabled:NO];
   }
   else
   {
      [thingSwitch setEnabled:YES];
      [booSwitch setEnabled:YES];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: But doing it inline like you have done how do I access the switches in other code because I don't have reference anymore?

Comment: @jdog: Why are you accessing it in other methods and how are you accessing it ?